# How do I scale Kafka Streams app running on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams App which runs on a pod in Kube cluster.

Trying to find a way for Kube to scale up/down the pods based on kafka topic lag.

Has anyone walked the path before and willing to share some details ?.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: You need to consider the number of partitions of your topic which you are consuming.
as if you have X partition then you can have X consumers consuming at the same time and scaling up for more than X consumers (pods) will not be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scaling up based on the lag, your app should be able to publish metrics (Using micrometer for example) use meter type (Gauge https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges)

Then you will need to collect the metrics using monitoring system (prometheus for example)

scale up/down based on the value of the meter/metric.

(Check this sample project as example https://github.com/learnk8s/spring-boot-k8s-hpa)

Note: But consider my comment as the max number of allowed consumers >= number of topic partitions